Troubleshooting Tomcat 10.1 Deployment Issues: Resolving Access Problems in IDEA and Standalone Environments
In IDEA
i followed the jetbrains offical toturial to use tomcat but always fail, even cannot be available to tomcat home page
directly
i tried to launch tomcat without IDEA but still failed, this time i can see the home page, but i have no access to samples of tomcat
1. Use tomcat in IDEA
It didn’t work at first, and then I read the official jetbrains tutorial [https://www.jetbrains.com/guide/java/tutorials/working-with-apache-tomcat/]
Followed step by step. At first he said the error was normal, but later he solved it but I still haven't.
Later I found a few more blogs and followed them, but it was still useless. After reading the logs, everything was normal, but the homepage could not be opened in the browser.
2. Open tomcat directly

It is slightly better than using IDEA. You can see the tomcat homepage, but its samples cannot be opened, the same 404
Tried to use maven to package the project into war and put it in tomcat's webapps directory, but still got the message "The requested resource [/xxxxxx/] is not available"

Attach logs
23-May-2024 14:17:11.558 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server.服务器版本: Apache Tomcat/10.1.23
23-May-2024 14:17:11.558 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log 服务器构建:        Apr 16 2024 12:17:18 UTC
23-May-2024 14:17:11.558 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log 服务器版本号:      10.1.23.0
23-May-2024 14:17:11.558 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log 操作系统名称:      Windows 11
23-May-2024 14:17:11.571 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS.版本:           10.0
23-May-2024 14:17:11.571 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log 架构:              amd64
23-May-2024 14:17:11.571 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java 环境变量:     E:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk-21
23-May-2024 14:17:11.571 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java虚拟机版本:    21.0.3+7-LTS-152
23-May-2024 14:17:11.571 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM.供应商:        Oracle Corporation
23-May-2024 14:17:11.571 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:     E:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.1
23-May-2024 14:17:11.571 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:     E:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.1
23-May-2024 14:17:11.571 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log 命令行参数：       -Djava.util.logging.config.file=E:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.1\conf\logging.properties
23-May-2024 14:17:11.571 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log 命令行参数：       -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
23-May-2024 14:17:11.571 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log 命令行参数：       -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
23-May-2024 14:17:11.571 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log 命令行参数：       -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
23-May-2024 14:17:11.571 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log 命令行参数：       --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
23-May-2024 14:17:11.571 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log 命令行参数：       --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
23-May-2024 14:17:11.571 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log 命令行参数：       --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
23-May-2024 14:17:11.571 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log 命令行参数：       --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
23-May-2024 14:17:11.571 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log 命令行参数：       --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
23-May-2024 14:17:11.571 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log 命令行参数：       -Dcatalina.base=E:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.1
23-May-2024 14:17:11.571 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log 命令行参数：       -Dcatalina.home=E:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.1
23-May-2024 14:17:11.571 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log 命令行参数：       -Djava.io.tmpdir=E:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.1\temp
23-May-2024 14:17:11.587 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent 在java.library.path:[E:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk-21\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;E:\Program Files\Python\Scripts\;E:\Program Files\Python\;E:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk-21\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;E:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation\bin\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\Bandizip\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;E:\mingw64\bin;E:\Program Files\Git\cmd;E:\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;E:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin;E:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.1\bin;E:\Program Files\Redis\;C:\ServletDevel;C:\Users\jackw\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;F:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.3.3\bin;;E:\Users\jackw\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;%DevEco Studio%;C:\Users\jackw\AppData\Local\Programs\Ollama;E:\ProgramFiles\md5sum-1.22\;E:\ProgramFiles\Maven\apache-maven-3.9.6\bin;D:\ProgramFiles\altera\13.1\modelsim_ase\win32aloem;E:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1\bin;;;.]上找不到基于APR的Apache Tomcat本机库，该库允许在生产环境中获得最佳性能
23-May-2024 14:17:11.758 信息 [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init 初始化协议处理器 ["http-nio-8080"]
23-May-2024 14:17:11.772 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load 服务器在[354]毫秒内初始化
23-May-2024 14:17:11.814 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal 正在启动服务[Catalina]
23-May-2024 14:17:11.814 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal 正在启动 Servlet 引擎：[Apache Tomcat/10.1.23]
23-May-2024 14:17:11.829 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR 正在部署web应用程序存档文件[E:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.1\webapps\hello.war]
23-May-2024 14:17:12.089 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR web应用程序存档文件[E:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.1\webapps\hello.war]的部署已在[260]ms内完成
23-May-2024 14:17:12.089 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR 正在部署web应用程序存档文件[E:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.1\webapps\test1Todo.war]
23-May-2024 14:17:12.659 信息 [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars 至少有一个JAR被扫描用于TLD但尚未包含TLD。 为此记录器启用调试日志记录，以获取已扫描但未在其中找到TLD的完整JAR列表。 在扫描期间跳过不需要的JAR可以缩短启动时间和JSP编译时间。
23-May-2024 14:17:12.659 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR web应用程序存档文件[E:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.1\webapps\test1Todo.war]的部署已在[570]ms内完成
23-May-2024 14:17:12.659 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR 正在部署web应用程序存档文件[E:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.1\webapps\TodoApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war]
23-May-2024 14:17:12.910 信息 [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars 至少有一个JAR被扫描用于TLD但尚未包含TLD。 为此记录器启用调试日志记录，以获取已扫描但未在其中找到TLD的完整JAR列表。 在扫描期间跳过不需要的JAR可以缩短启动时间和JSP编译时间。
23-May-2024 14:17:12.926 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR web应用程序存档文件[E:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.1\webapps\TodoApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war]的部署已在[267]ms内完成
23-May-2024 14:17:12.926 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR 正在部署web应用程序存档文件[E:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.1\webapps\todoList-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war]
23-May-2024 14:17:13.332 信息 [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars 至少有一个JAR被扫描用于TLD但尚未包含TLD。 为此记录器启用调试日志记录，以获取已扫描但未在其中找到TLD的完整JAR列表。 在扫描期间跳过不需要的JAR可以缩短启动时间和JSP编译时间。
23-May-2024 14:17:13.347 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR web应用程序存档文件[E:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.1\webapps\todoList-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war]的部署已在[421]ms内完成
23-May-2024 14:17:13.347 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR 正在部署web应用程序存档文件[E:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.1\webapps\todotest0523.war]
23-May-2024 14:17:14.115 信息 [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars 至少有一个JAR被扫描用于TLD但尚未包含TLD。 为此记录器启用调试日志记录，以获取已扫描但未在其中找到TLD的完整JAR列表。 在扫描期间跳过不需要的JAR可以缩短启动时间和JSP编译时间。
23-May-2024 14:17:14.131 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR web应用程序存档文件[E:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.1\webapps\todotest0523.war]的部署已在[784]ms内完成
23-May-2024 14:17:14.131 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory 把web 应用程序部署到目录 [E:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.1\webapps\docs]
23-May-2024 14:17:14.160 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Web应用程序目录[E:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.1\webapps\docs]的部署已在[29]毫秒内完成
23-May-2024 14:17:14.160 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory 把web 应用程序部署到目录 [E:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.1\webapps\manager]
23-May-2024 14:17:14.179 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Web应用程序目录[E:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.1\webapps\manager]的部署已在[19]毫秒内完成
23-May-2024 14:17:14.179 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory 把web 应用程序部署到目录 [E:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.1\webapps\ROOT]
23-May-2024 14:17:14.194 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Web应用程序目录[E:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.1\webapps\ROOT]的部署已在[15]毫秒内完成
23-May-2024 14:17:14.194 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory 把web 应用程序部署到目录 [E:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.1\webapps\test]
23-May-2024 14:17:14.194 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Web应用程序目录[E:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.1\webapps\test]的部署已在[0]毫秒内完成
23-May-2024 14:17:14.194 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory 把web 应用程序部署到目录 [E:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.1\webapps\web_servlet_hello_war]
23-May-2024 14:17:14.226 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Web应用程序目录[E:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.1\webapps\web_servlet_hello_war]的部署已在[32]毫秒内完成
23-May-2024 14:17:14.226 信息 [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start 开始协议处理句柄["http-nio-8080"]
23-May-2024 14:17:14.242 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start [2464]毫秒后服务器启动


Is it possible to share any sample project, so we could check it locally?
